# How do I send a gallery image to a listview widget which is located in another activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

So just to describe the app im building, there are 3 buttons on the home screen, "Data Input", "Info Display" and "Exit". When user clicks "Data Input", they get to fill in some EditText boxes with info and also UPLOAD AN IMAGE from gallery. Once they click a "Save" button on the page, all data entered will be sent to a ListView widget in the "Info Display" screen. However my problem now is that I have managed to get the EditText values to the list view throught the use of Sqlite, but i currently have no clue on how to get the image which was uploaded from the gallery to the ListView widget

These are the working codes I have(only missing the image part)

TouristHelper

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class TouristHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "assignment.db";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;

public TouristHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    //will be called once when the database 1s not created
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tourist_table ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            " Vactivity TEXT, Vdate TEXT, Vdescription TEXT);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    //Will not be called until SCHEMA_VERSION increases
    // Here we can upgrade the database e.g. add more tables
}

/*Read all records from restaurants_Table */
public Cursor getAll() {
    return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT _id, Vactivity, Vdate, Vdescription " +
                    "FROM tourist_table ORDER BY Vactivity", null));
}

public Cursor getById(String id) {
    String[] args = {id};
    return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT _id, Vactivity, Vdate, Vdescription" +
                    " FROM tourist_table WHERE _ID = ?", args));

}

public void insert  (String Vactivity, String Vdate,
                     String Vdescription) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put("Vactivity", Vactivity);
    cv.put("Vdate", Vdate);
    cv.put("Vdescription", Vdescription);

    getWritableDatabase().insert("tourist_table", "Vactivity", cv);
}

public void update(String id, String Vactivity, String Vdate,
                   String Vdescription) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String[] args = {id};
    cv.put("Vactivity", Vactivity);
    cv.put("Vdate", Vdate);
    cv.put("Vdescription", Vdescription);

    getWritableDatabase().update("tourist_table", cv, "_ID = ?", args);
}
public String getID(Cursor c) { return (c.getString(0)); }

public String getActivity(Cursor c){
    return (c.getString(1));
}
public String getDate(Cursor c){
    return (c.getString(2));
}
public String getDescription(Cursor c){
    return (c.getString(3));
}
}
```

InfoDisplay

```
public class InfoDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {
private Cursor model = null;
private VietnamAdapter adapter = null;
private ListView list;
private TouristHelper helper = null;
private TextView empty = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info_display);
    empty = findViewById(R.id.empty);
    helper = new TouristHelper(this);
    list = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    model = helper.getAll();
    adapter = new VietnamAdapter(this, model, 0);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (model != null) {
        model.close();
    }
    model = helper.getAll();
    if (model.getCount() > 0) {
        empty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    adapter.swapCursor(model);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    helper.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}


private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            model.moveToPosition(position);
            String recordID = helper.getID(model);
            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(InfoDisplay.this, DataIn.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID", recordID);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
};

static class DataHolder {
    private TextView VietACTI = null;
    private TextView VietDATE = null;
    private TextView VietDES = null;

    DataHolder(View row) {
        VietACTI = row.findViewById(R.id.VAct);
        VietDATE = row.findViewById(R.id.VDate);
        VietDES = row.findViewById(R.id.VDes);
    }
    void populateFrom(Cursor c, TouristHelper helper) {
        VietACTI.setText(helper.getActivity(c));
        VietDATE.setText(helper.getDate(c));
        VietDES.setText(helper.getDescription(c));
    }
}

class VietnamAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    VietnamAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        DataHolder holder = (DataHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(cursor, helper);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        DataHolder holder = new DataHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return (row);
    }
}
}
```

DataIn

```
public class DataIn extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText Vactivity;
private EditText Vdate;
private EditText Vdescription;
private Button buttonSave;

private Button buttonImg;
ImageView imageView;
private Bitmap imageToStore;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

private TouristHelper helper = null;
private String touristID = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_input);
    Vactivity = findViewById(R.id.activity);
    Vdate = findViewById(R.id.date);
    Vdescription = findViewById(R.id.description);
    buttonSave = findViewById(R.id.button_save);
    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(onSave);
    buttonImg = findViewById(R.id.imginput);
    buttonImg.setOnClickListener(onImg);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    helper = new TouristHelper(this);

    touristID = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
    if (touristID != null) {
        load();
    }


    /*list = findViewById(R.id.Data);
    adapter = new DataAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);*/
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    helper.close();
}

private void load() {
    Cursor c = helper.getById(touristID);
    c.moveToFirst();
    Vactivity.setText(helper.getActivity(c));
    Vdate.setText(helper.getDate(c));
    Vdescription.setText(helper.getDescription(c));
}
View.OnClickListener onImg = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
        /*Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE*/);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "pick an image"), RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }
};
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        /*String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();*/
        // String picturePath contains the path of selected Image
        imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    }
}


private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //read data from restaurantName EditText
        String nameStr = Vactivity.getText().toString();
        String dateStr = Vdate.getText().toString();
        String desStr = Vdescription.getText().toString();

        if (touristID == null) {
            helper.insert(nameStr, dateStr, desStr);
        }
        else {
            helper.update(touristID, nameStr, dateStr, desStr);
        }

        // To clase current Activity class and exit
        finish();
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At this point you have two options:

- Save the image in the private storage of your app and save on the DB the URI to this image so you can load it later.
- Having the Bitmap with the image get the ByteArray of the image and save it directly to the DB.

I prefer the first option, but the second one could do the job too, hope it helps you.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply!!! i am actually trying to work around the second option, but im not sure how to edit my code as im still kinda new to this.